# Поменять местами попарно элементы квадратной матрицы

Tags: c

Поменять местами попарно элементы квадратной матрицы относительно
правой(побочной) диагонали. Пример: элементы а[0][0] и а[n-1], [n-1] меняются местами и т.д. на СИ.

Подскажите можно ли тут использовать swap и если можно, то как.
И как работать только с элементами выше или ниже правой(побочной) диагонали.

Comment: Вы же сами написали - типа `swap(a[0][0],a[n-1][n-1])` - в чем проблема-то? Ну, а половину получить... заметьте, что у элементов выше этой диагонали номер столбца всегда больше номера строки. Намек понятен? :)

Comment: Ну примерно. Спасибо, сейчас попробую пойду.

Comment: Смотри у матрицы 3*3 индексы правой диагонали будут(a[2][0],a[1][1],a[0][2]) и тут не получается , что номер столбца всегда больше номера строки.

Comment: Да, это я не ту диагональ в уме представил :( Пардон. Сумма номера строки и номера столбца меньше `n-1`. Вроде так...

Comment: Все спасибо. Надеюсь получится